# getting subproperty null when receiving on web api 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

```
public class OrderModel
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string OrderNo { get; set; }
        public List<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    }
    public class OrderDetails
    {
        public int PrductId { get; set; }
        public string PrductName { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to pass Custom Class Object with complex property to webapi 2 using mvc 5.I am able to get all object property with thire values and complex property with count but not able to getting sub property value.i can see sub property name.

my ajax call

```
var DTO = $(form).serialize();
$.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:3413/api/order',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
            data:JSON.stringify(DTO);
                     success: function () {
                        alert('Added');
                    }
                });
```

And my Web API Method is

```
  public string GetGeneratedOrder([FromUri]OrderModel model)
        {
          // ...
        }
```

Any one tell mw,where i am wrong.any help appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more with code samples where is it not working? Your  OrderDetails class has two properties with same name "PrductId" but different type.

Comment: Thank you ACS for your response!,In my Order Detail 2nd property is ProductName.I have just updated my question.thank you for notice also.